# How to vary results, based on selected value?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filtering, lookup, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to only show values from a list for a given month, based on the desired month selected in a drop down.

Column B, C & D I have a list of items for a given month, each column representing a different month.

Row 2, 3, 4 is the expected quantity sold for each month.
I would like a drop down to be selected, picking a specific month, then showing how many of each item are expected to be sold.

[image: Image of example sheet structure]

Answer (score 1):

if the dropdown is like:

[image]

try:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, MATCH(B7, 1:1, 0))&":"&
          ADDRESS(5, MATCH(B7, 1:1, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

or try:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B1:Z5), 
 "where Col1 = date '"&TEXT(B7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")), 
 "offset 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use this:

```
=QUERY({A133:D136},"Select Col" & filter(COLUMN(B132:D132),B132:D132=H132))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just using filter like this:

```
=filter(B133:D136,B132:D132=H132)
```

[image]